# Bizarre bug: inputTextarea only hook its value to the last row in dataTable

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

The bug is the `inputTextarea` I have below. Only the last row can record any input from the `inputTextarea`, in other word, only the last row, hook it `value` to `#{PostComment.comment.comment}`. Why is this?

```
<h:form id="userCommentList" >
   <p:dataTable value="#{CentralFeed.profileComments}" var="item">
        <p:column>        
           <!-- Original Comment -->         
           <h:outputText value="#{item.comment}"/> &nbsp;              

           <!-- ****BUG IS THIS INPUTTEXTAREA BELOW*** -->
           <h:inputTextarea id="keyword" value="#{PostComment.comment.comment}"/> &nbsp;

           <p:commandButton actionListener="#{PostComment.postProfileComment(item.id)}"
                                             value="Post" update="userCommentList" />
        </p:column>                                                                                   
   </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

**EDIT**
I change the `inputTextarea` and `commandButton` like you suggest BalusC. And inside `Comment` entity I add in another field call `newComment`, so `Comment` look like this

```
Comment
+ id
+ comment
+ newComment --> I have @Transient to this field so it wont map to the database. I also set its default value to the empty string in the constructor
+ ...

...
<p:column>
    ...
    <h:inputTextarea id="keyword" value="#{item.newComment}" rows="2" />
    <p:commandButton actionListener="#{PostComment.postReply(item)}" value="Post" />
</p:column>
```

I hope the `item.newComment` would hold the value I just type in, so when I pass the object `item` to `postReply`, I can extract the content of newComment out, however it is an **empty string**. So whatever I type in does not bind to `newComment`. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in essence binding the value of multiple textareas in a table to **one and same** bean property. During request processing JSF will update this property with the value of *all* textareas in the table, each overriding the previous one everytime until with the one in the last row. That's why you will see only the value of one in the last row.

You need to bind the textarea value to the row object, which is `#{item}` in your case. E.g.

```
<h:inputTextarea id="keyword" value="#{item.newComment}"/>
```

Comment: is the `newComment` mean anything special or is it just a field inside my object, BalusC?

Comment: It's just an example. You can even use `#{item.comment.message}`. As long as it ends up in a `String` property.

Comment: I think you might have misunderstand me a bit. What I want is: whatever I type into this inputTextarea, that information will  create a new entry in my dataBase. It seems to me what you suggest, would override the value at the rows (since you bind to an exist object, not a new object). So inside my `PostComment` bean, I have `Comment comment = new Comment()`, so I want to bind whatever I just type to `comment`, so then once I persist, it become a new entry in `Comment` table.

Comment: Just do this job in `postProfileComment()` method. Check if the new comment has been entered, then persist it.

Comment: Hi BalusC, been busy so I havent got a chance to test it out. Well, I finally tried out your idea, but I still ran into some problem. I updated my original post, will you please take a look at them?

Comment: Interesting. Is it also empty when you traverse it from the list/datamodel directly instead of the passed-in argument? I'd however expect both to point to the same reference... What's the bean scope? Request or View?

Comment: Request scoped, BalusC. And I believe they both point to the same reference, but let me make.

Comment: I tested it with DataModel. `newComment` still is empty if I use `getRowData`.

Comment: Odd. Try `<h:commandButton>` or `<p:commandButton ajax="false">` to exclude one and other.

Comment: I tried that, does not fix it. Could this be because the `List` is not in managed state?

Comment: Is the submitted value present as request parameter? (check by Firebug, Fiddler or `getRequestParameterMap()`). I should maybe also note that I am still assuming that you didn't change other parts of the code since the original problem of only the last value being submitted, e.g. adding a nested form, a rendered/disabled attribute, etc.

Comment: OK, it's been submitted, but the model is not been updated. Isn't there an `immediate="true"` on either input or button? Remove it. If that was not the cause, I'd start debugging to see if the getter of the datamodel returned the right datamodel and the setter of the `newComment` was invoked anyway and that during the right phases. I suspect a mistake in datamodel loading/preserving and that the model cannot be found or that it was been overridden with a new reload.

Comment: well there is no `immediate=true`, and but setter method of newComment got invoke twice. One is to set the value that I just type to the `newComment`, the second time, set empty string to the newComment

Comment: That second set is suspicious. Don't you have another input field which sets the same property somewhere further in the table?

Comment: ohhh yeah, I have another one down, that explain the second setter, damn, I am stupid

Comment: I am sorry but how can I check what phase does DataModel get call, like what you mention earlier?

Comment: Log `FacesContext#getCurrentPhaseId()` in the getter or determine it in the variables section of the debugger.

Comment: it is at phase 5, `INVOKE_APPLICATION`

Comment: Well, I'd expect to see it only inside the action method, not in the getter (or you must be calling the getter from inside the action method instead of just accessing the local variable?)

Comment: That is correct, I call the getter of my DataModel from the action method. My DataModel is in my SessionScoped bean, and my action method is in RequestScoped bean.

Comment: OK, is your comment thing now working? Cheers, I'm going offline in order to buy myself a new laptop :)

Comment: Well hope you get a good deal on your laptop. Well it still not working. But now I know why the `newComment` got reset. If you take a look at my code above, dataTable invoke getProfileComments(). And in there, via my EJB, I query the entity, then I set up my DataModel here. this method get call a lot when I submit the comment. I debug, this method get call more than 10 times, going through 1-4 phase, each phase call multiples time. Is it normal? But what reset `newComment` is right after the `setNewComment()`, getProfileComments() got call, which then query the entity, hence reset what I type

Comment: From my comment above, I have a question. Is it normal to have getProfileComments() call over 12 times going through phase 1-4, each phase call this method 3-4 times. Right after this, `setNewComment()` get called, then immediate `getProfileComments()` get called again with phase id 5. Then `postReply()` inside RequestScoped bean `PostComment` get call, then `getProfileComments()` get call again with phase id 6 (3-4 times). This is definitely not normal. Definitely something wrong here. Any idea why, balusC?

Comment: Since this is a new problem, I guess I make a new post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973198/hdatatable-valuemybean-xxx-getxxx-get-called-so-many-times-why . I rewrite the code in the simplest form to make sure I did not make any mistake. If you have sometimes, please take a look at them. Thank you for your help

Comment: I've answered your other question. That it's called many times is normal, it's just to **access** the model data. Data loading should however definitely not go in the getter. As to the deal, well, I'm hesitating between a Dell Inspirion 17 and HP Pavilion DV7 :) I'll read some reviews and decide tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you BalusC. Base on your answer, I guess if I move the query database off the getter, then it should fix my bug. Let me try that. About the laptop, have you ever think of going for a MAC. I doubt it the first time but man, I love it now :D

Comment: Move the business logic off the getter fix my issue. Thank you. Ohh one more thing, when i see you wrap DataModel around the List, and later edit the list like add or delete entry, I dont see u re-update the DataModel. Does DataModel smart enough to know that the List is changes.

Comment: Indeed, it just holds the reference to the list, not the list itself. Nice thing, OO, huh? :)