# <h:dataTable value=#{myBean.xxx}>: getXxx() get called so many times, why?

Tags: java, jsf, datatable, jsf-2, getter

Simple piece of code about `dataTable`. `CentralFeed` is SessionScoped Bean, and `PostComment` is RequestScoped Bean

```
<h:form id="table">
    <h:dataTable value="#{CentralFeed.profileComments}" var="item">
        <h:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{item.comment}"/><br/>
            <h:inputTextarea value="#{item.newComment}" rows="2"/><br/>
            <h:commandButton value="Post" action="#{PostComment.postReply(item)}" />
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

inside `CentralFeed.java`

```
private List<NewsFeed> profileComments = null;

public List<NewsFeed> getProfileComments() {
    PhaseId currentPhaseId = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getCurrentPhaseId();
    profileComments = scholarBean.findProfileCommentsByUserId(getSelectedUser().getId());
    //model = new ListDataModel<NewsFeed>(profileComments);
    return profileComments;
}
```

My problem is that `getProfileComments()` get called a lot. `currentPhaseId` will tell us at what phase does the method got called. When the page first load, `getProfileComment` get call around **5 times**, at phase 6 - `RENDER_RESPONSE`. The page have a `inputTextarea`, so I type in there something, and click `Post` (the commandButton). Then `getProfileComment` get called another **12 times** going through phase 1->4. Each phase call this method **3-4 times**. Then after that, the setter method of the attribute `newComment` get call (so setNewComment() get call), the `getProfileComment` get call again at `phase 5`. Then `postReply()` get call, then `getProfileComment` get call again for another **5 times** at `phase 6`. What is going on? Is it suppose to be like this? If you look at my `getProfileComment`, via my EJB `scholarBean`, I actually query the database, so having to query the database like 20 times like this is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, getters can be called multiple times during a request. It doesn't harm as long as it does its sole job properly: returning the bean property. However, in your example you're loading the list straight in the getter method! This should be avoided. Initializing/loading of the model should go in bean's constructor or `@PostConstruct` or any event based methods like the action method. They get called only once. The getters should only return model data and nothing more (apart from some trivial logging or lazy loading).

#### See also:

- [Why does JSF call getters multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times)

Comment: Yup. Just like you said. Getter should just return value, not business logic. Once I took the business logic, I immediately solve my other problem. Thank you.